# How to fix an HRESULT: 0x8150002E Exception

Tags: powershell, comobject

**Background:** I'm running a

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
```

within Powershell 5.1.17134.590, but getting a

> "Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} from the 
>   IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 8150002e Exception from HRESULT: 0x8150002E"

**Question**: How can I find the root cause of the issue or look up the HResult to aid with troubleshooting?

**What I have tried:** 
I have googled for HRESULT exceptions - but was not able to find a matching result. This also includes sites with error lookups:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecCrypto/common-hresult-values
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/705fb797-2175-4a90-b5a3-3918024b10b8
- https://errorcodelookup.com/

Comment: Are you perhaps repeating the `$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application` without ever quitting it and removing the Com object from memory? This error usually means that the maximum number of possible instances of Internet Explorer for the client environment were already created and the client computer has no resource left to continue creating more Internet Explorer instances, but the user is still trying to create more Internet Explorer windows.

Comment: This is the correct answer, in my script to be sure i do Stop-Process IEXPLORE beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Internet Options >> Advanced Tab >> Un-select "enable third-party browser extensions"